# Setting default values for inherited property without using accessor

Tags: objective-c, subclass, accessor, ivar, declared-property

I always see people debating whether or not to use a property's setter in the `-init` method. My problem is how to create a default value in a subclass for an inherited property. Say we have a class called `NSLawyer` -- a framework class, that I can't change -- with an interface that looks like this:

```
@interface NSLawyer : NSObject {
    @private
    NSUInteger _numberOfClients;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger numberOfClients;

@end
```

And an implementation that looks like this:

```
@implementation NSLawyer

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _numberOfClients = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now let's say I want to extend `NSLawyer`. My subclass will be called `SeniorPartner`. And since a senior partner should have lots of clients, when `SeniorPartner` gets initialized, I don't want the instance to start with `0`; I want it to have `10`. Here's SeniorPartner.m:

```
@implementation SeniorPartner

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        // Attempting to set the ivar directly will result in the compiler saying, 
        // "Instance variable _numberOfClients is private."

        // _numberOfClients = 10; <- Can't do this.

        // Thus, the only way to set it is with the mutator:
        self.numberOfClients = 10;

        // Or: [self setNumberOfClients:10];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

So what's a Objective-C newcomer to do? Well, I mean, there's only one thing I can do, and that's set the property. Unless there's something I'm missing. Any ideas, suggestions, tips, or tricks?

Comment: perhaps change `@private` to `@protected`

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I should have mentioned that my issue stems from not being able to modify the superclass. I'm subclassing AppKit classes like `NSButton` or `NSPathControl`, and because our good friends at Apple like to watch me hurt, all of their classes have their ivars in their header files (almost as to mock me), but I can't touch them. :-( What about those situations?

Comment: Can you use the c arrow operator? `self->numberOfFriends`?

Comment: @stevesliva I actually tried that and I got the same error. :-( I'm just surprised that nobody has really mentioned this before. Am I the only person who subclasses Apple classes? It's been a huge pain in the ass, but it's not like when I was forced into working with a Magento installation after knowing HTML for a few months. If you want to know pain. That's pain.

Comment: Yes we subclass Apple classes all the time. But accessing private ivars and methods is a really bad idea, they may change at any time--don't do it. It is only recently that ivars can be declared in the implementation so legacy code has them in the .h file. In most cases Apple puts private ivars and methods in a private .h file that is not provided.

Comment: @BenStock Is it safe to assume that in real life, your `init` methods return `self`?

Comment: @jlehr Haha, I should probably fix that, huh? Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Zaph Yeah, I get that. That's what I'm saying … I don't want to access private ivars. I just want to initialize an ivar from a superclass with a different value. That's all. I guess my biggest problems with Obj-C thus far have more to do with that fact that Apple still has a bunch of legacy code intermixed with new code, so being new to the language (and Cocoa), it can get confusing in regard to best practices and what not. Thank you for helping me wade through the old stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do exactly has you have; call the accessor. The declaring class typically avoids calling its own accessors in `init` to avoid accidentally calling an overridden accessor in a *subclass* that might rely on the consistency of data you haven't initialized yet. Your *superclass* on the other hand should be completely consistent by the time the subclass's `init` is run, so there is no problem using superclass accessors at that time.

Consider the common and general case: you want to set your `transform` in a `UIView` subclass. How would you solve that other than call `setTransform:`? Subclassing non-Apple code is no different.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I didn't even think about it like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make it @protected. It is very rare to make an ivar or property private these days. Private ivars and/or properties are better declared in the implementation. For that matter @protected ivars/properties are rarely seen in Objective-C but perfectly fine.

Using a setter either as a method or with dot notation is just wrong (yes it works but is really bad form), if you want use setters/getters declare a property.

Comment: When I want something "private," I usually extend the class `@interface` in the implementation (which is what I think you mean by "declared in the implementation"), but if you see my comment to Kevin (above), I personally can't change the superclass. I totally forgot to mention that in my initial post. I'm not sure what your last sentence means exactly. What's the point of a setter if not to "set." If I have a property `color`, I can't say `self.color = [NSColor redColor];`? I thought Apple recommended using accessors/mutators within the class for KVC. Or are you talking about just in `-init`?

Comment: If you have a property `color` you can say `self.color = [NSColor redColor];`, that is shorthand for `[self setColor:[NSColor redColor]];`, it is not the the "C" usage of ".".

Comment: I got ya. I misunderstood what you meant. My bad. Thanks for your input!